# Excel interop adding slashes in my number formatting string

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting, excel-interop, custom-formatting

I'm trying to set a number format (South African Rand currency, no decimals) to a range like so:

```
range.NumberFormat = "_ R * # ##0_;";
```

where `range` is of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range`

however when I open the spreadsheet and check the formatting string by choosing custom format the string now looks like this:

```
_ \R * #\ ##0_;
```

and these added slashes means that only the first thousand separator (a space) is present and the rest are left off.

I've also tried this:

```
range.NumberFormat = @"_ R * # ##0_;";
```

I tried MSDN but this paricular doc reads like gibberish to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat.aspx

but it does the same thing. Anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `NumberFormatLocal` property seems to have solved it for me:

```
range.NumberFormatLocal = "_ R * # ##0_;";
```

No idea why though... and happy to accept a more complete answer that explains why there is a problem and why this fixes it.