# Excel Interop adds slashes to NumberFormat

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I wanted to set the NumberFormat of a whole column via Excel Interop:

```
column.NumberFormat = "# ##0";
```

However, Excel adds an additional slash (opening the document shows `#\ ##0`).

I've found the following related question: [Excel interop adding slashes in my number formatting string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650219/excel-interop-adding-slashes-in-my-number-formatting-string)

However, using `column.NumberFormatLocal`, I've run into an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unable to set the NumberFormatLocal property of the Range class

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have more than 64k cells in that column?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I have 72160 rows in that column.

Comment: Did you try `@"# ##0"?` It works on my machine...

Comment: have you tried escaping the space with quotes? `"#' '##0"`

Comment: Right, are you - by any chance - running Excel in 2007 compat. mode?

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet: Nope, Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by using the en-US separator instead:

```
column.NumberFormat = "#,##0"; // Note the comma
```

I'm not sure why. My system locale and my application's `CultureInfo` are both `de-AT`. Also my system thousands separator is de-AT (i.e., a space).

For some reason Excel Interop is nevertheless requiring the en-US separator.

Comment: Just as a FYI: The fact you need to use the en-US separator is because you're using "NumberFormat", if you'd like to use formatting w/ your locale you'd need to use "NumberFormatLocal" (which for some reason did give you an exception)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - do you know by chance why I got the exception?

Comment: I've seen this happen when Excel > 2007 is running in Excel-2007 compatibility mode (e.g. by opening an .xls rather than an .xlsx file), and the accessed range contains more than 64k rows. But since you said that you were using Excel 2013 in regular mode, I am at a loss here.

Comment: This could have something to do with how the application is started.  I haven't ever tried using alternate localizations, but I recall reading something about how Excel, when opened through the interop, requires some special flag or something to open in anything other than en-US.  I can't find the article anymore, or any other details on it, so maybe my memory is inventing things....